# In python, how to split a tuple and pass as separate arguments of map function

Tags: python

Here's what I want to do

```
class Vertex:
  def __init__(self, x,y):
    # ...

coords = [(0,0),(10,10)]
v0, v1 = map(lambda x,y: Vertex(x,y), coords)
```

The above code won't work, because the coord tuples get passed as `x`, and there is nothing for `y`

A workaround that works is

```
class Vertex:
  def __init__(self, x,y):
    # ...

coords = [(0,0),(10,10)]
v0, v1 = map(lambda coord: Vertex(coord[0],coord[1]), coords)
```

But the first solution looks more elegant to me. Probably I've to add an extra step to split the coord tuple. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use tuple-unpacking to call the `Vertex` constructor:

```
coord = (0, 0)
Vertex(*coord)
```

Or for your example:

```
v0, v1 = map(lambda coord: Vertex(*coord), coords)
```

Alternatively, since you are on Python 2, you can also make the lambda accept a tuple:

```
v0, v1 = map(lambda (x, y): Vertex(x, y), coords)
```

Instead of calling `map` (which actually returns a generator in Python 3, so your code wouldn’t work there), you can also use a list comprehension to create the Vertex objects:

```
v0, v1 = [Vertex(*coord) for coord in coords]

# or unpack the coordinates as suggested by NPE
v0, v1 = [Vertex(x, y) for x, y in coords]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put parentheses around `(x, y)`:

```
v0, v1 = map(lambda (x,y): Vertex(x,y), coords)
#                   ^   ^
```

Edit: it turns out the above won't work in Python 3 (PEP 3113).

The following generator expression will work in both Python 2 and 3:

```
v0, v1 = (Vertex(x, y) for x, y in coords)
```

Comment: Do note that the first option is removed in Python 3, so will raise `SyntaxError` there.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Interesting. Didn't know that.

Comment: [PEP 3113 -- Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

Answer (score 1):

use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) along with [unpack operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) *:

```
map(Vertex, *zip(*coords))
```

also, your `__init__` signature is possibly wrong, as I assume it misses `self` argument:

```
>>> class Vertex:
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         self.x, self.y = x, y
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'vertex({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)
... 
>>> 
>>> coords = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
>>> tuple(map(Vertex, *zip(*coords)))
(vertex(1, 2), vertex(3, 4))
```